# How to get Multiple Key Value in Dart Http

Tags: api, http, flutter

Please How Can I get this kind of API response in Flutter using http with FutureBuilder.

```
"GLODATA": {
            "1000": {
                "pname": "GLO 1.0GB/14days",
                "price": "470",
                "pld": "1000"
            },
            "1600.01": {
                "pname": "GLO 2.0GB/30days",
                "price": "940",
                "pld": "1600.01"
            },
            "3750.01": {
                "pname": "GLO 4.5GB/30days",
                "price": "1900",
                "pld": "3750.01"
            },
            "5000.01": {
                "pname": "GLO 7.2GB/30days",
                "price": "2430",
                "pld": "5000.01"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, you will need to do something like this:

Api:

```
Future<http.Response> getData() async {
    final _api = "http://yourendpointhere";

    http.Response response = await http.get(_api);

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception("Request failed...");
    }

    return response;
  }
```

Then consume your api:

```
http.Response response = await _apiInstance.getData();

if (response.body != null && response.body.isNotEmpty) {
  String source = Utf8Decoder().convert(response.bodyBytes);

  Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> data = Map();
  data = Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(source));
}
```

After that, you can create a factory constructor in your model class, receiving that map and turning it into an instance of your class.